# JXA keystroke does not work with special characters

Tags: applescript, javascript-automation

I'm trying to setup a simple Apple JXA script to write the well-known shrug emoji to screen (it simulates the key press I guess).  Every thing I try produces this "¯\_(a)_/¯".  I'm assuming since I'm using keystroke to simulate key press and I don't have a japanese keyboard that I'm always going to get that.  Maybe I should be copying the string to clipboard instead?

Here's my code so far:

```
// Shrug Script
// ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
//
// contains special character:
// ツ
// KATAKANA LETTER TU
// Unicode: U+30C4, UTF-8: E3 83 84

// thought maybe I needed to decode it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}

// this is the newer "Script" aka Javascript way
var sysEvents = Application('System Events');

// this didn't work:
// sysEvents.keystroke("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯");

// this doesn't work either
sysEvents.keystroke("¯\\_("+ decode_utf8("\xE3\x83\x84") +")_/¯");
```

Answer (score 2):

ok so adding it to my clipboard and immediately pasting it was a lot easier.  It's not a direct answer to my question but the final result is what I wanted.

Apple Script version:

```
# Shrug Script
# ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
#
# contains special character:
# ツ
# KATAKANA LETTER TU
# Unicode: U+30C4, UTF-8: E3 83 84

set the clipboard to "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
```

JXA version:

```
var app = Application.currentApplication()
    app.includeStandardAdditions = true
var seApp = Application('System Events')

// set current app's clipboard  
app.setTheClipboardTo("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯")
// paste!
seApp.keystroke('v', { using: 'command down' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend Services for this kind of task as they can directly manipulate text in almost any application; no need for hacky kludges like GUI Scripting. Very easy to make a new Service in Automator that will output a piece of text, plus you can bind it to a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences when done. Here's an example you can easily adapt:

[Creating an osx service to insert the current date and time](https://andytaylor.me/2012/11/10/creating-an-osx-service-to-insert-the-current-date-and-time/)

Comment: I've made a service before but not sure why I didn't consider it.  I'll try this as well.  thanks!